# incorrect clion warning for 'condition always false'

Tags: c++, ide, compiler-warnings, clion

I just coded this in my c++ project in clion

```
int step_size_x = someValue;
int step_size_y = anotherValue;

while (!(step_size_x == 1 && step_size_y == 1)) {
        step_size_x = (step_size_x != 1) ? (step_size_x / 2) : step_size_x;
        step_size_y = (step_size_y != 1) ? (step_size_y / 2) : step_size_y;
    }
```

and clion gives me a warning, that the second statement (line 5) in my while loop `step_size_y != 1` will always be false.

I could not comprehend how it comes to that conclusion so I quickly threw [this](http://cpp.sh/9asti) into a c++ online shell - and it seemes to side with me.

Since I do not have that much experience with c++ I really am not convinced to have found a bug and am rather tending towards that the answer is stupefying obvious. In that case, please enlighten me, what am I missing here?

Note:

`step_size_y` will be set external files, therefore the compiler should be able to predict its value. Anyway, if it *was* `1` the warning would appear in the second half of the `while()`'s brackets.

Here is a screenshot of the warning:
[image: clion warning]

Comment: clion is not a C++ compiler. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Only a C++ compiler fully understands C++ code. So, CLion misparses some C++ code, and issues a bogus warning. Nothing else to see here.

Comment: But if any of the steps' initial value (i.e., either `someValue` or `anotherValue`) is zero or negative then the loop will be infinite (because the corresponding step will eventually become `0` and will never reach `1`). Maybe this causes that warning, I'm not sure. Do you ensure before entering the loop that `someValue` and `anotherValue` are at least `1`?

Comment: @heapunderrun yes, this can not happen but it is enforced elsewhere. I assume the warning would be worded differently if that was the problem.

Comment: What is the exact warning? Please add it to the question.

Comment: It may be taking a prior code where `anotherValue` is set into account.